# Issue in creating Azure HDInsight with Data lake using Template Deployment

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-lake

I'm trying to create **Azure HDInsight with Data lake using Template Deployment**. But I'm Facing an issue in executing the template because of what i think the reason would be the "Service Principle Name" integration with azure data lake store.

Error:

*"message": "DeploymentDocument 'AmbariConfiguration_1_7' failed the validation. Error: 'Error while getting access to the datalake storage account demodls: Error while getting the OAuth token from AAD for AppPrincipalId XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXX-XXXXX.*

Please find below screenshot for more details.

[image]

I have tried creating AD webapp and assigned "Owner" role for the app. Then I have assigned it to Subscription's owner. Then added "Data Lake Permission" for the app. but still I think I might be missing.

Cluster Integration Snippet

```
"properties": {
                "clusterVersion": "[parameters('clusterVersion')]",
                "osType": "Linux",
                "tier": "standard",
                "clusterDefinition": {
                    "kind": "[parameters('clusterKind')]",
                    "configurations": {
                        "gateway": {
                            "restAuthCredential.isEnabled": true,
                            "restAuthCredential.username": "[parameters('clusterLoginUserName')]",
                            "restAuthCredential.password": "[parameters('clusterLoginPassword')]"
                        },
                        "core-site": {
                            "fs.defaultFS": "adl://home",
                            "dfs.adls.home.hostname": "demodls.azuredatalakestore.net",
                            "dfs.adls.home.mountpoint": "/clusters/democluster/"
                        },
                        "clusterIdentity": {
                            "clusterIdentity.applicationId": "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX",
                            "clusterIdentity.certificate": "[parameters('identityCertificate')]",
                            "clusterIdentity.aadTenantId": "https://login.windows.net/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX",
                            "clusterIdentity.resourceUri": "https://management.core.windows.net/",
                            "clusterIdentity.certificatePassword": "[parameters('identityCertificatePassword')]"
                        }
                    }
                },
```

Here I have few doubts like

1. Is "SecureString" values like clusterpassword,sshpassword in "parameter.json" should be given as plaintext or i have to convert it into Securestring and give the secure string value to it?
2. The field "identityCertificate" should be "base64" encoded of "Certificate.pfx" file content or I'll have to convert it as Base64 -> SecureString and give it in parameter.json?

Help appreciated much ! Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Matt H

I have downloaded the template generated at portal when we create HDInsight even then it still wont work.

Please find my below powershell script.

```
 //To Create Resources
 $resourceGroupName = "demoesprg"
 New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Location "East US 2"
 $dataLakeStoreName = "demoespdls"
 New-AzureRmDataLakeStoreAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $dataLakeStoreName -Location "East US 2"
 Test-AzureRmDataLakeStoreAccount -Name $dataLakeStoreName
 $myrootdir = "/"
 New-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -Folder -AccountName $dataLakeStoreName -Path $myrootdir/clusters/demoespcluster

 $templatefilepath = "C:\Azure-saml\template.json"
 $SSHpass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Demoesp1234$" -AsPlainText -Force

  //Create .pfx certificate
 $certFolder = "C:\Azure-saml\certs"
 $certFilePath = "$certFolder\demoespcert.pfx"
 $certStartDate = (Get-Date).Date
 $certStartDateStr = $certStartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
 $certEndDate = $certStartDate.AddYears(1)
 $certEndDateStr = $certEndDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
 $certName = "demoespcert"
 $certPassword = "democert123$"
 $certPasswordSecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $certPassword -AsPlainText -Force 
 $cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName $certName -CertStoreLocation cert:\CurrentUser\My 
 $certThumbprint = $cert.Thumbprint
 $cert = (Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\CurrentUser\My\$certThumbprint) 
 Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $cert -FilePath $certFilePath -Password $certPasswordSecureString 
 $certificatePFX = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($certFilePath, $certPasswordSecureString)
 $credential = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($certificatePFX.GetRawCertData())

 //create ActiceDriectory Application
 $application = New-AzureRmADApplication `
     -DisplayName "ESPSPN" `
     -HomePage "https://demoespcluster.hdinsight.net" `
     -IdentifierUris "https://demoespcluster.hdinsight.net" `
     -CertValue $credential  `
     -StartDate $certificatePFX.NotBefore  `
     -EndDate $certificatePFX.NotAfter 
 Start-Sleep -Seconds 20

 //Create Service Principla
 $applicationId = $application.ApplicationId
 $servicePrincipal = New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $applicationId
 $objectId = $servicePrincipal.Id

 //Assign Permissions
 Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry -AccountName $dataLakeStoreName -Path / -AceType User -Id $objectId -Permissions All
 Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry -AccountName $dataLakeStoreName -Path /clusters -AceType User -Id $objectId -Permissions All
 Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry -AccountName $dataLakeStoreName -Path /clusters/demoespcluster -AceType User -Id $objectId -Permissions All


 //Execute Scripts
 $tenantID = (Get-AzureRmContext).Tenant.TenantId
 $secureCert = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String((Get-Content $certFilePath -Encoding Byte))
 //$dsecureCert = ConvertTo-SecureString $secureCert -AsPlainText -Force

 New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -TemplateFile $templatefilepath `
    -identityCertificate $secureCert `
    -identityCertificatePassword $certPasswordSecureString `
    -clusterName  $certName `
    -clusterLoginPassword $SSHpass `
    -sshPassword $SSHpass `
    -servicePrincipalApplicationId $applicationId
```

Error:

> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 11:15:00 PM - DeploymentDocument
>   'AmbariConfiguration_1_7' failed the validation. Error: 'Error while
>   getting access to the datalake storage account demoespdls: Access
>   denied.

What Am i missing here?

**UPDATE:** The Script is right but my self signed certificate had a problem. Once used a valid certificate, I was able to create the cluster successfully!! Thanks.

Comment: Hi Karthick. Thanks for this info. Does the deployment succeed when you deploy through the portal UI? Also, for the PowerShell deployment script, is the folder /clusters/demoespcluster/ empty? If not, you may need to go to the portal UI or PowerShell and recursively give access to the application before continuing, since there may be files that the cluster can't access without such permissions. Here's a guide for that process: https://1drv.ms/w/s!AvdZLquGMt47gz3ks4YwQRMXGi3j

Comment: I was able to create it via portal, only from powershell I'm facing this issue. And the folders are empty as well.

Comment: I was able to create the HDInsight cluster with Datalake store with above script successfully. The above script hold good but problem is my self-signed certificate was not properly generated. I downloaded the certificate via Azure Portal's When creating HDInsight with Datalake and used the same for creating AD Service Principal and it Worked !!. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

`identityCertificate` should be the base64-encoded string representation of the contents of the certificate .pfx file. It's labeled as type `SecureString` in the ARM template definition file so that the plaintext isn't stored/returned when you fetch deployment histories going forward. Marking fields with `SecureString` helps make sure that passwords and other such fields don't get persisted in your deployment history.

One easy way to troubleshoot how you're authoring your cluster creation ARM template is to go to the Azure Portal, and create the cluster just as you want in the template. Just before clicking 'Create' on the 'Summary' step, download the ARM template to see what's getting deployed. There's a link next to 'Create' to do this.

I expect you'll notice differences in how you're specifying your primary ADLS account. Go with how it's configured in the downloaded ARM template, and you should be good to go.